# Setup Project/Wizard [serial key] Visual Studio 2010

Tags: key, setup-project

I want to create a setup for my app in Visual Studio 2010 but i want to implement the serial key check when someone tries to install?
Is it possible in setup project?

Answer (score 0):

No, not really. The usual way is to validate the key when the user enters it during the initial UI sequence, but Visual Studio installer setups do not support adding custom action code during the UI to do the validation. If you add a custom action to verify it, all custom actions in VS setups run after everything is installed, so the user experience is unpleasant - they enter the key, the install proceeds and then right at the end it says the key is wrong and the entire install rolls back.

It's often better to do this in the app itself so they can't use the app until they enter the correct key, and code to do this can verify properly and with a modern UI.